# Spring google OAuth2 token validation

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm developing rest api in spring for my company. I need to secure it using google OAtuh2. Firstly I  used jwt token validation. Frontend app obtains token_id andd pass it to backend resource server. I've read that I sholud use access tokens instead of id_tokens (is that right?). For using opaque tokens introspection I need to provide introspection uri. I can't find it. Does google auth server support token introspection?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [you should use access-tokens only](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/) to secure requests to **resource-server(s)**. ID tokens are for **clients** to get user-info.

Using access-token introspection has serious performance impact compared to JWT decoding: resource-server must issue a query to authorization-server for each and every request it processes (when JWT validation can be done locally with authorization-server public key retrieved only once). I recomand you don't do that.

If you cannot configure authorization-server to add the claims you need to JWT access-tokens, you should consider using an authorization-server capable of identity federation in front of it. It is very common to do so when several etherogenous identity sources are used (Google + Facebook + Github + LinkedIn + corporate LDAP for instance), but it would work with a single one too. Keycloak for instance does that and allows you to put whatever you need in access-tokens.